# Does the fact that matrices $A, B$ are similar imply that $A+cI$ is similar to $B+cI$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be similar $n \times n$ matrices over (say) $\mathbb{R}.$  Is it the case that $A+cI$ is similar to $B+cI$?

Here is an argument (which seems too good to be true...)

Since $A, B$ are similar, they have the same Jordan form. So we can write $PAP^{-1}=QBQ^{-1}=J$ for $P, Q$ invertible matrices.

Hence we have $P(A+cI)P^{-1}=PAP^{-1}+cI= J+cI.$ Similarly, we find $Q(B+cI)Q^{-1}=J+cI.$  Hence $A+cI$ and $B+cI$ are both similar to $J+cI$ and hence similar to each other.

Is this correct?

Comment: More direct, $A$ and $B$ being similar means by definition that there is a $P$ with $B = PAP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fine, but it seems to me that you do not need Jordan form to do this. Since $A$ is similar to $B$, exists an invertible $P$ such that $B = PAP^{-1}$. Hence: $$P(A + cI)P^{-1} = PAP^{-1} + P(cI)P^{-1} = B + cI$$
since everything commutes with the identity. Notice that the same $P$ that worked for $A$ and $B$ worked for $A + cI$ and $B + cI$. A priori, it could have been another matrix.