# Proof of invertibility problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

How do I do this problem?

.....

Comment: Do you know what does similarity mean?

Comment: Excuse me, it is not the right duplicate, looking for another one...

Comment: Could not find any duplicates easily (maybe the question is too easy) so reopened and answered the question inestead.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/905875. But since I accidentally closed this question as another duplicate before, I cannot vote to close right now!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

An $n\times n$ matrix $B$ with entries in a field $K$ is similar to another such matrix $A$ if (and only if) $B$ is the matrix of the linear operator $L_A:K^n\to K^n$ defined by left-multiplication by$~A$ on *some* basis $\mathcal E$ of$~K^n$ (on the standard basis the matrix would be just $A$ of course). But then the matrix of $L_A-\lambda\,\mathrm{id}$ with respect to $\mathcal E$ is $B-\lambda I$ (since $I$ is the matrix of $\mathrm{id}$ with respect tot *any* basis). If $A-\lambda I$ is invertible, then so is $L_A-\lambda\,\mathrm{id}$, and therefore its matrix$~B-\lambda I$ with respect to$~\mathcal E$.

Answer (score 0):

$(A-\lambda I_n)$ is invertible 
$\implies$ $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$
 $\implies$$\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$
 $\implies$ $(B-\lambda I_n)$ is one-one
 $\implies$  $(B-\lambda I_n)$ is invertible .
 We can reverse this argument to prove the other way around.